# Excel 2013 - Referencing multiple checkboxes on a different sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

My supervisor wants me to do something I have never done before, nor can I find a solution online.

The spreadsheet is set up with five separate checkboxes (Let's say Checkbox1, Checkbox2...), each representing a corresponding value, 1-5. (Like, check Checkbox1 if this service was (1) Unacceptable. Check Checkbox2 if this service was (2) Acceptable. Check Checkbox3 if this service was (3) Successful, and so on)

On a separate spreadsheet, in one cell, I am supposed to represent which of the boxes was chosen in numerical form. For example, if the person ticked the box for 3 on Sheet1 (Checkbox3), I would have to represent on Sheet2 the number '3'. If they checked Checkbox4 on Sheet1, I would have to display the number '4' on Sheet2.

Here's an image for better understanding:

[image]

And I guess I am just at a loss of how to represent one of five check boxes in a numerical value on another sheet. I am really struggling, so any help?

Comment: Do you just not know how to use radio buttons?  I just checked and simple cell references to another sheet work fine i.e. Sheet2!$E$3

Comment: @Tyson makes a good point - if these are five mutually exclusive options, you want them to be radio buttons and not check boxes.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this guide to put the *Option boxes* on Sheet1:

http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-buttons.html

Supposing you put 4 boxes, then use this code on *Sheet1*:

```
Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()
    Dim wkb As Workbook
    Set wkb = ThisWorkbook
    wkb.Sheets(2).Cells(1, 1) = 2
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton2_Click()
    Dim wkb As Workbook
    Set wkb = ThisWorkbook
    wkb.Sheets(2).Cells(1, 1) = 2
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton3_Click()
    Dim wkb As Workbook
    Set wkb = ThisWorkbook
    wkb.Sheets(2).Cells(1, 1) = 3
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton4_Click()
    Dim wkb As Workbook
    Set wkb = ThisWorkbook
    wkb.Sheets(2).Cells(1, 1) = 4
End Sub
```

Comment: From his picture radio buttons is what he needs.  This isn't needed with radio buttons.